# Pyplot shows image without plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had a look at other questions on that regard, but in all other cases people had

```
%matplotlib inline
```

which caused plots to show without being prompted. I don't have it.

My plotting code looks like this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17,8))
ax = plt.hist(results_df['Diff'], bins=100, density=True, histtype='step')
plt.savefig('backtester_results/figures/rf_model_lag_{n_days}_data_{lag}_lag.png',
            format='png')
```

It's an output from testing machine learning model I'm working on and I want to put it to run for 40 hours and there will be few hundred of these plots generated in the process. So I really want them not to just get saved in a folder and not take up memory.

Do you know how to suppress this behaviour or what could be causing it?

I'm using Python 3.6 and Spyder editor. In Spyder settings I have Graphics backend set up as 'Automatic'.